# Display Products Shipping Classes for just one in WooCommerce order edit page

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using [Display Products Shipping Classes in WooCommerce order edit page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47560951/display-products-shipping-classes-in-woocommerce-order-edit-page/47565488#47565488) answer code
and it works fine but how can I see just one of the 2 shipping classes?

For example If I have **dhl** and **dpd**, when someone get 2 items one with **dhl** and one with **dpd** i wanna see just the **dpd** one.

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly you want to show the *"dpd"* shipping class on all items ordered if there is at least one with the *"dpd"* shipping class.
Otherwise each product will show the respective shipping class.

To do this you will need to access the order object and check the shipping class of each product ordered using a control variable.

Example:

You have an order with **3 products**. One of them has the *"dpd"* shipping class. It will show:

```
#1 Product - Shipping class: DPD
#2 Product - Shipping class: DPD
#3 Product - Shipping class: DPD
```

You have an order with **2 products**. One has the shipping class *"dhl"* and the other *"fedex"*. It will show:

```
#1 Product - Shipping class: DHL
#2 Product - Shipping class: FedEx
```

Try this:

```
// Display the shipping classes names in Order edit line items
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_order_itemmeta', 'custom_admin_order_itemmeta', 15, 3 );
function custom_admin_order_itemmeta( $item_id, $item, $product ) {

    if ( ! is_admin() ) return; // only backend

    $dpd_check = false;
    $dpd_slug  = 'dpd'; // enter the shipping class slug

    global $post;
    // get the WC_Order object
    $order = wc_get_order( $post->ID );
    foreach ( $order->get_items( 'line_item' ) as $order_item ) {
        $order_product = $order_item->get_product();
        $shipping_class_slug = $order_product->get_shipping_class();
        // if at least one product has the shipping class equal to "$dpd_slug"
        if ( $shipping_class_slug == $dpd_slug ) {
            $dpd_check = true;
            break;
        }
    }

    // only for "line_item"
    if ( $item->is_type( 'line_item' ) ) {
        $label = __( 'Shipping class:', 'woocommerce' );
        // if in the order there is at least one product with the shipping class "$dpd_slug"
        if ( $dpd_check ) {
            // shows the "$dpd_slug" shipping class for all ordered items
            $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $dpd_slug, 'product_shipping_class' );
            $class_name = esc_html( $term->name );
        } else {
            // otherwise it shows the shipping class of the product
            $shipping_class = $product->get_shipping_class();
            if ( $shipping_class ){
                $term = get_term_by( 'slug', $shipping_class, 'product_shipping_class' );
                $class_name = esc_html( $term->name );
            }
        }
        if ( isset( $class_name ) && $class_name ) {
            echo '<div class="wc-order-item-ship-class"><strong>' . $label . '</strong> <span style="color:#ca4a1f;">' . $class_name . '</span></div>';
        }
    }

}
```

*The code has been tested and works. Add it to your active theme's functions.php.*